# Gravity Forms - upload fields not working tabbed view

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Maybe somebody solved this before:

Currently if you put a Gravity form into Bootstrap Tabs (basic nothing fancy), the upload fields stop working on mobile view (mobile devices or chrome mobile emulation).

Basic code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="document-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#documents" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="true">FIRST MENU</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="false">SECOND MENU</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">THIRD MENU</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">FOURTH MENU (where the upload doesn't work)</button>
    </li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="documents" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">[gravityform id="111" title="true" description="true" ]</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">[gravityform id="222" title="true" description="true" ]</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">[gravityform id="333" title="true" description="true" ]</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">[gravityform id="444" title="true" description="true" ]</div>
</div>
```

I've tested this and if you just put the form on the FIRST tab, and it's viewable on page load, the upload works correctly.

If the Gravity form is in the 2nd/3rd/4th tab, and the tab is hidden - the upload field doesn't work.

I reported this to GF team, but not seeing any movement.

Is there a way to initialize the form in some way?

WHAT I TRIED

- tried updating the plugin
- tried to move the form around
- tried to put the form on first tab (which worked) - the requirement is to put it on last tab though
- tried to put JS to see if the click is being registered on the button and yes the click is being put on the upload button. So there's no interference from outside elements. It almost seems like some JS is not being loaded because the tab is hidden.

UPDATE:
Looks like even if you put the form into:

```
<div style="display:none">[gravityform id="444" title="true" description="true" ]</div>
```

The upload field stops working.

Something must be wrong with their logic for hidden fields.

UPDATE:
It has been 3 weeks now that I reported the case to Gravity Forms support.

The only thing they are good at is blaming me, my pc, my browser, my site, cats, dogs and flying monkeys, but not themselves for broken functionality. No wonder they have removed their plugin from the WP plugin directory.

What I found:

- issue happens on Iphone + Safari / Chrome on a hidden form (display:none). Android works.

Here is an example page (click on "Show Form"):
https://excitement-malvaceous-3fdd22.gravitydemo.com/12345-2

[testing in BrowserStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hXOH.png)

Just nothing happens.

Well, looks like I'm going to need to roll up the sleeves on this one.